# Pandas GroupBy and SQL Where Clause parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a SQL query string output that takes in multiple parameters in the WHERE Clause from a Pandas DataFrame column using groupby. What is the best way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Contact Name':['John Doe','John Doe','Jane Doe','Jim Doe','Jim Doe'],
    'Email Address': ['john.doe@gmail.com','john.doe@gmail.com','jane.doe@gmail.com','jim.doe@gmail.com','jim.doe@gmail.com'],
    'Contract No':['2851','2852','2853','2854','2855'],
})
```

From the above example, I need to get 3 different SQL queries that go as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN ('2851', '2852')
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN ('2853')
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN ('2854', '2855')
```

Comment: What was wrong with the approaches you found from your research? Why do you think they're not best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's [use parametrized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to give hackers one less [entryway into our databases](https://www.theverge.com/2018/8/22/17716622/sec-business-wire-hack-stolen-press-release-fraud-ukraine):

```
sqls = []
args = []
for key, grp in df.groupby(['Contact Name', 'Email Address']):
    arg = tuple(grp['Contract No'])
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN ({})'.format(','.join(['%s']*len(arg)))
    sqls.append(sql)
    args.append(arg)

for sql, arg in zip(sqls, args):
    print(sql, arg)
    # SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN (%s) ('2853',)
    # SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN (%s,%s) ('2854', '2855')
    # SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN (%s,%s) ('2851', '2852')
```

To execute the parametrized sql, use the [2-argument form of `cursor.execute`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

```
for sql, arg in zip(sqls, args):
    cursor.execute(sql, arg)
```

Comment: Thank you @unutbu, I was looking for a solution that was foolproof against injection. Also, how do I eliminate the trailing comma and %s appearing in the print statements?

Comment: The `print(sql, arg)` is there only to show you the values in `sqls` and `args`. In practice, to avoid SQL Injection, you would call `cursor.execute(sql, arg)` exactly the way they have been defined -- with `sql` containing those `%s` placemarkers. The database adapter will insert the arguments into the sql with proper escaping for you.

Comment: Note that the proper placemarker depends on which database adapter you are using. For example, MySQLdb and psycopg use `%s` placemarkers, but `sqlite3` uses `?` placemarkers.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced `%s` with `?` to work for `pyodbc` and `mssql`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. I just needed to use a lambda function alongwith groupby.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Contact Name':['John Doe','John Doe','Jane Doe','Jim Doe','Jim Doe'],
    'Email Address':['john.doe@gmail.com','john.doe@gmail.com','jane.doe@gmail.com','jim.doe@gmail.com','jim.doe@gmail.com'],
    'Contract No':['2851','2852','2853','2854','2855'],
})

df2 = df1.groupby(['Contact Name','Email Address'])['Contract No'].apply(lambda x: ','.join('\'' + x + '\'')).reset_index()

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    print('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Contract No] IN (' + row['Contract No'] + ')')
```